# Sort Json in Flutter

Tags: json, list, flutter, sorting

I get the following Json output from url:

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "FX Intraday (5min) Time Series",
        "2. From Symbol": "USD",
        "3. To Symbol": "TRY",
        "4. Last Refreshed": "2020-12-18 21:55:00",
        "5. Interval": "5min",
        "6. Output Size": "Full size",
        "7. Time Zone": "UTC"
    },
    "Time Series FX (5min)": {
        "2020-12-18 21:55:00": {
            "1. open": "7.6181",
            "2. high": "7.6256",
            "3. low": "7.6181",
            "4. close": "7.6181"
        },
        "2020-12-18 21:50:00": {
            "1. open": "7.6232",
            "2. high": "7.6244",
            "3. low": "7.6181",
            "4. close": "7.6181"
        },
        "2020-12-18 21:45:00": {
            "1. open": "7.6244",
            "2. high": "7.6244",
            "3. low": "7.6208",
            "4. close": "7.6232"
        },
        "2020-12-18 21:40:00": {
            "1. open": "7.6234",
            "2. high": "7.6262",
            "3. low": "7.6201",
            "4. close": "7.6244"
        },
            .
            .
            .
        } }
```

I need to sort the 'Time Series FX(5min)' values by the keys (date) in reverse order , so the first position has the latest date time. Then I want to extact the first (latest) 288 elements.

What I need in the returned list(s) is only the date time and the value of '4. close'

for example something like this:

```
list<String> Date_time = [2020-12-18 21:55:00, 2020-12-18 21:50:00, 2020-12-18 21:45:00,...]
list<double> values = [7.6181, 7.6181, 7.6232,...]
```

Here is part of the code:

```
void fetchDayValues() async {
    final response = await http.get(
        'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=FX_INTRADAY&from_symbol=' +
            symbol.substring(0, 3) +
            '&to_symbol=' +
            symbol.substring(4) +
            '&interval=5min&outputsize=full&apikey=NS8IP79OIRVVH7Q0');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final jsonInput = json.decode(response.body) as Map;
      final data = jsonInput["Time Series FX (5min)"] as Map;
                          
    }
  }
```

I looked at other answers but cannot find a solution to my problem. How to do it? Thanks

Comment: This is a basic list sorting problem but I will still write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code sorts the data by the date. It uses string comparison for simplicity.

You can try it on Dartpad.

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  final raw_string = '''{"Time Series FX (5min)": {
        "2020-12-18 21:50:00": {
            "1. open": "7.6232",
            "2. high": "7.6244",
            "3. low": "7.6181",
            "4. close": "7.6181"
        },
        "2020-12-18 21:55:00": {
            "1. open": "7.6181",
            "2. high": "7.6256",
            "3. low": "7.6181",
            "4. close": "7.6181"
        },
        "2020-12-18 21:40:00": {
            "1. open": "7.6234",
            "2. high": "7.6262",
            "3. low": "7.6201",
            "4. close": "7.6244"
        },
        "2020-12-18 21:45:00": {
            "1. open": "7.6244",
            "2. high": "7.6244",
            "3. low": "7.6208",
            "4. close": "7.6232"
        }}}''';
  
  final decoded = jsonDecode(raw_string)["Time Series FX (5min)"] as Map;
  
  final sortedKeys = decoded.keys.toList()..sort((a,b)=> b.toString().compareTo(a.toString()));
  
  final sortedValues = sortedKeys.map((k)=> decoded[k]["4. close"]).toList();
  
  print(sortedKeys);
  print(sortedValues);
}
```